# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de generar un reporte exportando los datos de una base de datos en sql server express a un archivo excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp.net-core

Deseo realizar este proceso en asp.net core 2.1 mvc mediante C#, soy novato en este tema pero necesito realizarlo para un proyecto. No encuentro tutoriales que sean adecuados a la versión del framework. Agradecería cualquier ayuda, sugerencia o indicación de algún tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

para base de datos siempre me a paresido la mejor opcion hacer todo por consola:

```
sqlcmd -S server_name -i query.sql  -o SQLout.csv -W -w 1024 -s","
```

esto no creara un excel pero creara un "csv" que puedes luego importar en excel